# Parse RequestBody as two different objects in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application (`2.5.5`) I get a large JSON body in the `POST` request to a specific endpoint. On that request I need to get both the parsed object and that whole object as a string to do some validation. The JSON object contains a lot of information that I don't need so that is not included in the Object so I can't convert it to a string.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @PostMapping("")
    public void example(
        @RequestBody String stringBody,
        @RequestBody ExampleRequest exampleRequest
    ) {
        // Validate request with 'stringBody'
        // Do things with 'exampleRequest'
    }

}
```

The best idea I had so far is to just use `@RequestBody String stringBody` and then convert that string to a JSON object but that is really not the ideal solution.

I know that you can't have two `@RequestBody` but I really need to somehow have both.

Comment: Why do you need the whole object as a `String` to do some validation? What kind of validation?

Comment: @JoãoDias I need to verify the Ed25519 signature

Comment: To be more exact I need to implement this in Spring Boot https://canary.discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#security-and-authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is your best option.
For that I suggest you create a custom annotation as follows:

```java
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidJsonSignature { }
```

Now you need to implement the custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`:

```java
public class JsonSignatureValidationArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
 
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
 
    public JsonSignatureValidationArgumentResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(ValidJsonSignature.class) != null;
    }
     
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        String jsonPayload = StreamUtils.copyToString(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     
        // Do actual validation here
     
        if (// Valid) {
            // If valid, then convert String to method parameter type and return it
            return objectMapper.treeToValue(objectMapper.readTree(jsonPayload), methodParameter.getParameterType());
        } else {
          // Throw exception if validation failed
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you need to register `JsonSignatureValidationArgumentResolver` as an argument resolver:

```java
@Configuration
public class JsonSignatureValidationConfiguraion implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
 
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new JsonSignatureValidationArgumentResolver(objectMapper));
    }
}
```

Last but not the least, you need to annotate the Controller attribute with `@ValidJsonSignature` as follows:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @PostMapping("")
    public void example(@ValidJsonSignature ExampleRequest exampleRequest) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's perfect! And there is no issues with using `httpServletRequest.getInputStream()`? I messed around with `HandlerInterceptor` and the app always "crashed" on the actual handler

Comment: To be sure nothing better than actually test it with your exact use case ;). In theory, this works but we can't be sure until we see it running.

Comment: Works like a charm! The only issue with the code you posted is `@RequestBody @ValidJsonSignature ExampleRequest exampleRequest`. `@RequestBody` overrides the `@ValidJsonSignature` so it never gets executed. If we leave it with just `@ValidJsonSignature ExampleRequest exampleRequest` it works as it should.

Comment: Awesome. I've updated my answer so that others may benefit from it. Thanks!